# SSRS How to add a tablix footer group

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

SSRS Newbie and feeling a bit silly.

Im working on my first report(in VS 2008) and cant seem to work out the group footer for my tablix. This must sound really simple but how do I add it and configure it to show on every page of my report? I have the group header working fine but I want the overall totals to display at the bottom of each page in my report. Every tutorial/website I check doesnt really seem to explain it very well

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a footer, it will appear on every page by default.  There are two properties that can remove the footer from the First and/or Last page of the report.  However, by default, the footer is active on all pages of a report.

So basically, if you add data to the footer, it should work.

Comment: I had done that originally but it wasnt rendering how I wanted. Is there not a footer group similar to the header group that I could add to my table in the body which I can then repeat on each page?

Comment: Yes.  You can specify a Header and a Footer on the Table Control.  Then there is a "RepeatOnNewPage" property on those specific table rows that can be set to TRUE to enable that functionality.